# How do i detect a long press?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I'm wondering how I should go about detecting a long press on a UIButton I have? I've heard of UILongPressGestureRecognizer but am totally unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectorname)];
[anyView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[longPressGesture release];
```

Comment: This doesn't offer proper desired behavior on a UIButton

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, but you could start a `NSTimer` when the button is hit, and then when the timer goes off check to see if it is still down.